# Why is PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS not working?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The following test program produces the expected answer '1' on all platforms I have tried it on, except for one hosting company's platform where it gives '0'.  Can anyone think of a reason why this should be?  MySQL version 8.0.26 and PHP 8.2.9.

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$db_database = "your_database";
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_login = "your_login";
$db_password = "your_password";

$dsn = "mysql:dbname=$db_database;host=$db_host";
$table = "found_rows_test";

$options = [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true];

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $db_login, $db_password, $options);

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (id varchar(10), data int, PRIMARY KEY(id))";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO $table (id, data) VALUES ('abcd', 1)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$sql = "UPDATE $table SET data=1 WHERE id='abcd'";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

echo $stmt->rowCount();
```

Comment: It only counts the updated rows. Because data is already 1 there's no update. You should check for the return value of execute() to know if the query itself was successful.

Comment: But if you set `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS` to `true`, then according to the manual it's supposed to count found rows, not changed rows: " PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS (int) Return the number of found (matched) rows, not the number of changed rows."   And that's what it does on every platform I have tried except this one particular one which behaves differently.

Comment: It seems to be known, but never fixed bug and told as unstable. https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#comment-276

Comment: It's strange that there only seems to be one platform out of many hundreds that this code is used on where there is a problem.  And that platform is running relatively recent versions of PHP and MySQL.  It feels more like there's some other setting in PHP or MySQL which is preventing this from working.

Comment: Could you paste your php.ini? (edit question) Do you run this script via CLI or via FPM?

Comment: I don't know how the script is being run and I don't have access to the php.ini file.  It's running on the free altervista.org hosting platform.  I've tried posting in their forum, but with no joy.

Comment: Then you should contact the hoster.

Comment: As I say, I have already contacted the hosting company, but so far they have been unable to help. I hope that someone in the wider community may be able to.

Comment: Without debugging information I am afraid we can not help.

Answer (score 0):

The hosting company say that they have found and fixed the problem, though I haven't been able to verify this yet as the fix will appear in the next version of PHP to be rolled out on their site. It turns out that they run "a modified version of PHP to make it more secure and optimised" ...